Discord Bot UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT when hosted in AWS EC2
I'm creating a discord bot that I want to host on AWS EC2 instances.
I am mainly following this post to configure my AWS: medium/aws-ecs-cluster-on-ec2-with-terraform.
What is not working:

The client.login({CLIENT TOKEN}) call seems to time out after 10 seconds so my bot is not spinning up.

ConnectTimeoutError: Connect Timeout Error
at onConnectTimeout (/app/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:190:24)
at /app/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:133:46
at Immediate._onImmediate (/app/node_modules/undici/lib/core/connect.js:174:9)
at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:476:21) {
code: 'UND_ERR_CONNECT_TIMEOUT'
}

What is working is:

EC2 instance are spinning up from my auto scaling group
Cluster is successfully running task to run my docker image in EC2 instance
Since tasks are failing, new tasks are spawning to take its place <-- this is really the behavior that I want to keep so my bot is always online

Attempts to fix:

Sent an axios.get("https://discord.com"): I've seen on other posts that it might be that I couldn't connect but this seemed to work fine.
Opening up traffic from all ports to my EC2 instance, Load Balancer, ECS Service (only to see if this is the issue): I thought maybe I wasn't getting approval through some channel
Verified that discord bot can run locally and on Docker

Here is code to reproduce issue:

Use Terraform to build out the AWS configuration

Find the pull commands for your ECR

Use those commands to build out the docker image and upload to the ECR

If a task is not automatically started to build out the container in your EC2, update the ECS service with force deployment


#main.tf
terraform {
  required_version = "1.9.7"
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_default_vpc" "main" {
  tags = {
    Name = "main"
  }
}

data "aws_region" "current" {}

data "aws_availability_zones" "available_zones" {}

resource "aws_default_subnet" "public_a" {
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available_zones.names[0]
  
  tags = {
    Name = "public subnet a"
  }
}

resource "aws_default_subnet" "public_b" {
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available_zones.names[1]
  
  tags = {
    Name = "public subnet b"
  }
}

resource "aws_default_subnet" "public_c" {
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available_zones.names[2]
  
  tags = {
    Name = "public subnet c"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_a" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_default_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = "172.31.128.0/20"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = "false"
  availability_zone       = data.aws_availability_zones.available_zones.names[0]

  tags = {
    Name = "private subnet a"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private_b" {
  vpc_id                  = aws_default_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = "172.31.144.0/20"
  map_public_ip_on_launch = "false"
  availability_zone       = data.aws_availability_zones.available_zones.names[1]

  tags = {
    Name = "private subnet b"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table" "main_private" {
  vpc_id = aws_default_vpc.main.id

  tags = {
    Name = "main private"
  }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_a" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.private_a.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.main_private.id
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "private_b" {
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.private_b.id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.main_private.id
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_exec_role" {
  name                = "ecs-exec-role"
  assume_role_policy  = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_task_role_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_task_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect  = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_exec_role_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_exec_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "mre" {
  name = "mre"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "mre_sg" {
  name_prefix = "mre-sg-"
  vpc_id      = aws_default_vpc.main.id

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 65535
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

data "aws_ssm_parameter" "ecs_ami" {
  name = "/aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id"
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_role" {
  name_prefix        = "ecs-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_ec2_role_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "assume_ec2_role_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]
    effect  = "Allow"

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "ecs_role_policy" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs_role.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role"
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ecs_profile" {
  name_prefix = "ecs-profile"
  path        = "/ecs/instance/"
  role        = aws_iam_role.ecs_role.name
}

resource "aws_launch_template" "mre_ec2" {
  name_prefix            = "mre-ec2-"
  image_id               = data.aws_ssm_parameter.ecs_ami.value
  instance_type          = "t2.micro"
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.mre_sg.id]

  iam_instance_profile { arn = aws_iam_instance_profile.ecs_profile.arn }
  monitoring { enabled = true }

  user_data = base64encode(<<-EOF
      #!/bin/bash
      echo ECS_CLUSTER=${aws_ecs_cluster.mre.name} >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config;
    EOF
  )
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "mre_asg" {
  name_prefix               = "mre-asg-"
  vpc_zone_identifier       = [
    aws_default_subnet.public_a.id,
    aws_default_subnet.public_b.id,
    aws_default_subnet.public_c.id
  ]
  min_size                  = 1
  max_size                  = 1
  health_check_grace_period = 0
  health_check_type         = "EC2"
  protect_from_scale_in     = false

  launch_template {
    id      = aws_launch_template.mre_ec2.id
    version = "$Latest"
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "mre"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "AmazonECSManaged"
    value               = ""
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "mre" {
  name = "mre-ec2"

  auto_scaling_group_provider {
    auto_scaling_group_arn         = aws_autoscaling_group.mre_asg.arn
    managed_termination_protection = "DISABLED"

    managed_scaling {
      maximum_scaling_step_size = 2
      minimum_scaling_step_size = 1
      status                    = "ENABLED"
      target_capacity           = 100
    }
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster_capacity_providers" "mre" {
  cluster_name       = aws_ecs_cluster.mre.name
  capacity_providers = [aws_ecs_capacity_provider.mre.name]

  default_capacity_provider_strategy {
    capacity_provider = aws_ecs_capacity_provider.mre.name
    base              = 1
    weight            = 100
  }
}
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "mre" {
  name          = "mre"
  force_delete  = true
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs_task_role" {
  name_prefix        = "ecs-task-role"
  assume_role_policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.assume_task_role_policy.json
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "mre_lg" {
  name = "/mre/mre-task"
  retention_in_days = 7
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "mre" {
  family             = "mre-task"
  task_role_arn      = aws_iam_role.ecs_task_role.arn
  execution_role_arn = aws_iam_role.ecs_exec_role.arn
  network_mode       = "awsvpc"
  cpu                = 256
  memory             = 256

  container_definitions = jsonencode([{
    name         = "mre-task",
    image        = "${aws_ecr_repository.mre.repository_url}:latest",
    essential    = true,
    portMappings  = [
      {
        containerPort = 80
        hostPort      = 80
      }
    ],

    logConfiguration = {
      logDriver = "awslogs"
      options = {
        awslogs-group         = "${aws_cloudwatch_log_group.mre_lg.name}"
        awslogs-region        = "${data.aws_region.current.name}"
        awslogs-stream-prefix = "mre"
      }
    }
  }])
}

resource "aws_security_group" "mre" {
  name_prefix = "mre-sg-"
  description = "Allow all traffic within the VPC"
  vpc_id      = aws_default_vpc.main.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = [aws_default_vpc.main.cidr_block]
  }

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = -1
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "mre" {
  name            = "mre"
  cluster         = aws_ecs_cluster.mre.id
  task_definition = aws_ecs_task_definition.mre.arn
  desired_count   = 1

  network_configuration {
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.mre.id]
    subnets         = [
      aws_default_subnet.public_a.id,
      aws_default_subnet.public_b.id,
      aws_default_subnet.public_c.id
    ]
  }

  capacity_provider_strategy {
    capacity_provider = aws_ecs_capacity_provider.mre.name
    base              = 1
    weight            = 100
  }

  load_balancer {
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.mre_lb_tg.arn
    container_name   = "mre-task"
    container_port   = 80
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [desired_count]
  }
  
  depends_on = [aws_lb_target_group.mre_lb_tg]
}

resource "aws_security_group" "load_balancer" {
  name_prefix = "lb-sg-"
  description = "security group for load balancer that allows HTTP/HTTPS port"
  vpc_id      = aws_default_vpc.main.id

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = [80, 443]
    content {
      from_port   = ingress.value
      to_port     = ingress.value
      protocol    = "tcp"
      cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    }
  }

  egress {
    protocol    = "-1"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}

resource "aws_lb" "mre_lb" {
  name               = "mre-lb"
  load_balancer_type = "application"
  subnets            = [
      aws_default_subnet.public_a.id,
      aws_default_subnet.public_b.id,
      aws_default_subnet.public_c.id
    ]
  security_groups    = [aws_security_group.load_balancer.id]
  
  tags = {
    Name = "mre-lb"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_target_group" "mre_lb_tg" {
  name_prefix = "mre-tg"
  vpc_id      = aws_default_vpc.main.id
  protocol    = "HTTP"
  port        = 80
  target_type = "ip"

  health_check {
    path                = "/"
  }
}

resource "aws_lb_listener" "mre_lb_listener" {
  load_balancer_arn = aws_lb.mre_lb.arn
  port              = 80
  protocol          = "HTTP"

  default_action {
    type             = "forward"
    target_group_arn = aws_lb_target_group.mre_lb_tg.arn
  }
}

//package.json

{
  "name": "mre",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node .",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^14.15.2"
  }
}

//app.js

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const discord_js_1 = require("discord.js");
// create a Discord client with the right intents
const client = new discord_js_1.Client({
    intents: [
        discord_js_1.IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds
    ]
});
client.once(discord_js_1.Events.ClientReady, readyClient => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${readyClient.user.tag}`);
});
client.login({CLIENT TOKEN});

#Dockerfile

#Pre build stage to install dependencies
FROM node:18-alpine AS pre-build

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

#Build stage
FROM node:18-alpine AS build

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=pre-build /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

RUN npm run build

#Production stage
FROM node:18-alpine AS production

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm ci --omit=dev

COPY --from=build /app/app.js ./app.js
COPY --from=build /app/node_modules ./node_modules

CMD ["node", "app.js"]

